# Why does this telescoping series end up with a 2 in the numerator?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, telescopic-series

I am confused about how to solve for this series:  $$f(x) = c/((x+1) (x+3))$$ for $x = 1, 2, 3...$  solving for $c$.  I see this is a telescoping series with a result of $1/(x+1) - 1/(x+3)$ but the solution I was given for this problem says this is equal to $2/((x+1)(x+3))$ and I do not see how it arrives at that. Any advice please?  Thank you!!

Comment: $\frac{1}{x+1} - \frac{1}{x+3} = \frac{2}{(x+1)(x+3)}$

Comment: There isn't any special tricks here: it's the usual process of adding/subtracting two fractions, by finding a common denominator first. Are you OK subtracting two fractions in general? For example, could you compute $\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{5}$?

Comment: Thank you Martin R. I did not know how to get the formula into the correct font.

Comment: Thank you Theo.  Yes it would be 5/15 - 3/15 = 2/15.  I think I am just confused with the variable in the denominator.  Would it just be ((x+3) - (x+1)) /((x+1) * (x+3)) ? OH wait! I see now in the numerator its x-x = 0 and then 3-1 =2.?

Comment: @pav Yes, exactly. You might also notice that I slyly chose $3$ and $5$, which were of the form $x + 1$ and $x + 3$ where $x = 2$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you!